# 'Sequence has no elements' Exception. Error Unity, WebGL

Tags: c#, php, database, unity-game-engine, phpmyadmin

questioned was moved to another area

Comment: `IEnumerator GetAllData()` is very strange. What you are trying to return? And why not `IEnumerable`?

Comment: I am returning the url of my localhost. I do this so I can use all of the data from the database in other c# classes by calling an instance of ServerManager.cs

Comment: but do you know why I am getting ''Sequence has no elements' Exception.' when I build a run on WebGL platform?

Comment: Can you include the full error and stack trace? Alsocan we see what `string data`'s value is when you get a re response from the server?

Comment: i can't show you string data but it is just all of data from my database. i will include the picture of the error I get.